# Unable to include libv8 in a c++ app

Tags: libraries, g++

I was trying to use the `libv8-3.8.9.20` package in my c++ script. The package is installed in `/usr/lib/` as supposed but if I try to compile my script using `g++ script.cpp -Iv8` command, nothing happens.

What should be in the script's header so I could use the library?
This is what I've tried:

```
#include <v8>
#include <libv8>
#include <libv8.so>
#include <v8.so>
```

On the next line was `using namespace v8` command.
When I do this, `g++` returns an error:

```
index.cpp:1:20: fatal error: libv8.so: No such file or directory
 #include <libv8.so>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

Or something like that.
I have even tried to compile it without the header but `g++` didn't like it.

Is it possible to use the library this way? And how?
Thank you, m93a

**EDIT:**
After installing `libv8-dev` (or `libv8-3.14-dev`, I've tried both) compiler throws:

```
index.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
index.cpp:10:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(v8::Isolate*&)’
   HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
                                   ^
index.cpp:10:35: note: candidates are:
In file included from index.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/v8.h:473:3: note: v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(const v8::HandleScope&)
   HandleScope(const HandleScope&);
   ^
```

And so on... (it's too long and still saying something's not found)
I'm using `g++ main.cpp -lv8` command.

Comment: Could add you `main.cpp` code to the question? if you still have it, now 6years ago.

Answer (score 3):

To use a library in a program you are writing (in C/C++ at least), you need not only the compiled library (the `.so` - *shared object* file) but also a header file, which describes the functions and data structures used by the library.

Header files are not usually installed by default. They are usually found in a package called `libwhatever-dev`, in this case `libv8-dev` which needs to be installed.

You then need the line:

```
#include <v8.h>
```

to include the V8 headers. When compiling, you'll also need to tell g++ to link with the v8 library (`-lv8`). V8 is a fairly complex beast, and it would probably be wise to find a working example or tutorial to see how they compile it.

Finally, a note on terminology: a *script* normally refers to code which is executed directly from the readable text form by an *interpreter* (such as `python`), whereas this has to be first compiled before it can be run.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yeah, that `-Iv8` was my fault. I've tried your solution - still not working - details at the bottom of my question. PS: If it's not a _script_, what is it? Just _code_?